# firebase is not defined in Angular app (after Firebase migration)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase

Hi I'm trying to retrieve information from my database on Firebase in angular. However, I get an error `'firebase is not defined'`

```
var config = {
    databaseURL: 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/face-find-31e52/database/data/',
};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);                           
    firebase.database().ref    
    ('/project/app-name/database/data').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {                                        
          $scope.data = snapshot.val();
    });
```

*note I don't have the user id in my url right now for authentication becauase I'm testing the app (solve one problem at a time right?)

I included the firebase library in my html before I linked my app.js

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

I also remembered to include this in my angular:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','firebase'])

.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera,$cordovaToast,$firebaseObject) {
```

Yes I"m building an ionic app, but I don't believe that this has any interference with firebase.Does anyone know why I can't retrieve the data? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you get any other errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angularfire 1.3 (current release as of writing) does not support the new Firebase SDK. Check out [this pull request](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/pull/717) for the 2.0 release of AngularFire. It should be in NPM and such soon :)

Comment: Ahh that sucks, but for anyone else, you can still use the old versions as they are backwards compatible even if you migrated to the new dashboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: For gods sake... I lost like an hour trying to figure out what the hell I was doing wrong with my dependency injections. Will teach me not to bower i <lib_name> stuff blindly... >_>